# Which is the lightest way to create a huge html list structure?

Tags: html, html-lists

I have to show a lot of elements in the side of a web page, in a list way. So the user can view it, add more in the fly, remove them, etc.

But the important thing is just the structure itself. I have been told that it could be thousands of elements. Leaving the desing apart, I'm wondering which would be the lightest structure for th HTML parser I can use. TRs? LIs? Block DIVs? Floating DIVs?

I would like to know the answer, I'm not asking for solutions like paging.

Lots of thanks in advance to everyone ;)

---

Because of noone seeming to know about specifical tests, references or something of evidential value, I mark this question as answered to thank the active participation, but if someone comes with further conclusions, they will be welcome!

Comment: It probably depends more on your CSS than on plain HTML elements.

Comment: @DmytroZarezenko, the list will contain names, and maybe an 'x' to delete a line

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario maybe you're right, maybe the markage will not have too much effect but the elements i put inside, choosing an image for the "x", etc...

Comment: I have asked, because UI structure depends on data. If this names are categorized, then you can create 2 lists with categories and names. For convenience.

Comment: @DmytroZarezenko, just simple data, think about what i said, for example a single list of maybe 5000 names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a list, isn't it? That give you one of the three: `ol`, `ul` or `dl`.

- If it's an **ordered list**, i.e. the order of the elements have meaning, use an `<ol>`.
- If it's an **unordered list**, i.e. the order of the elements have no meaning, use an `<ul>`.
- If it's a definition list, i.e. it lists definitions throughout the `<article>`, `<section>` or document, use a `<dl>`.

Whichever is more semantic. HTML is never about efficiency, it's about semantics. Write semantically, then you by definition write efficiently.

---

Regarding the display of such elements, it's more up to your CSS.

It doesn't matter what way you choose, no way in hell you can display thousands of items on the page at once, and hope the user to accept them all. A pagination of some sort is probably mandatory.

Comment: Wanting to list data doesn't force you to use a list markage. You can display your data wrappping it in different elements if you display them the correct way.

Comment: @Áxel: True, but it would make much more sense to someone without CSS (i.e. a blind person with a screen reader) to read your website if it were a list, rather than a bunch of divs which wouldn't make sense. Have a look at [**this**](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/164993/38223) answer regarding why should one bother marking up HTML semantically.

Comment: Really good answer, caring about accessibility, commonly forgiven issue. But in this case it's a limited access intranet accessed with a tablet, and I just don't want to crash the parser ;)

Comment: @Áxel: The parser won't crash over a very large list. Trust me. Unless you try to do crazy things, like animating them all individually together, which, based on that previous comment, you won't.

Comment: Also, have you considered that one day, sometime in the future, you may hire a person with disabilities? Wouldn't that be a shame if he couldn't use your apps? Or worse, you needing to modify that app to allow him to use it?

Comment: I'd love a world in which you could always do what is right in every situation. But this case is: the client asks for a private web for administrative purposes, and -crazily- asks that in one of the sections, side by side with a form, my web displays a list of names (that I'm predictind hundreds of items long) with no paging. I'm just wondering if there is a way to do this without getting it's tablet crashing. But I really appreciate your advices, I'm really into coding good practices.

Comment: @Áxel: Yes, a `<ul>` will do just fine.